# How to check if file is empty in dask python where filename is like A-*.txt

Tags: python, dask

I have give filename in cfg like  A-*.txt, where in location i have A-1.txtand A-2.txt.
So while reading dask csv , if any of the file is empty , then it shuld not read_csv. SO I tried with os.stat(A-*.txt).st_size !=0, but giving me error like this A-*.txt exist , it is not reading the file A-1.txt and A-2.txt from location .How to check it if i give it as A-*.txt pattern.

Thanks in advance

Comment: could you post the code of what you have tried and the error you are getting?

Comment: tempFile=A-*.txt if os.stat(tempFIle).st_size !=0: print(do something)

Comment: error i am getting is  Filenotfounderror - A-*.txt, in the location it is A-1.txt,A-2.txt,but in the configuration file of dask , i have given the input files as A-*.txt , so that it will take all the things whoch comes after "-"

Comment: dont post code or errors as comments. You have to edit your question and put there all relevant information properly formatted

Answer (score 0):

dask supports glob strings by default

```
import dask

df = dask.dataframe.read_csv('sampledata/A-*.txt', sep=' ', header=None, names=['contents']
    ).compute()

|    | contents         |
|---:|:-----------------|
|  0 | A-1.txt_contents |
|  0 | A-2.txt_contents |
|  0 | A-3.txt_contents |
```

If you have to manually check and build a list of empties, you could do something like this.

```
import os
import glob

files = glob.glob('A-*.txt')
nonzero_files = [ x for x in files if os.stat(x).st_size != 0 ]
```

out:

```
files = [
    'sampledata\\A-1.txt', 
    'sampledata\\A-2.txt', 
    'sampledata\\A-3.txt', 
    'sampledata\\A-4.txt'
    ]

nonzero_files = [
    'sampledata\\A-1.txt', 
    'sampledata\\A-2.txt', 
    'sampledata\\A-3.txt'
    ]
```

Comment: the problem is i am taking the list of files like this ..files=inputfiles.split(",").and then I tried applying as u said f=glob.glob(files) ..but it is throwing error as its not str object , not list

Comment: You'll have to put more details or a reproducible example in your question for us to help you. Just guessing at this point.